# pypandoc giving the error “RuntimeError: source_file is not a valid path

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, pypandoc

My Code:

[image]

Error:

> $ C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe
>   e:/PYTHON/pdf_word_converter.py Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:/PYTHON/pdf_word_converter.py", line 4, in 
>       conout = pypandoc.convert_file("E:\PYTHON\0267_Docusign.pdf", "docx", outputfile= "readme.docx")   File
>   "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pypandoc__init__.py",
>   line 137, in convert_file
>       raise RuntimeError("source_file is not a valid path") RuntimeError: source_file is not a valid path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the escape sequence.

Two options.

- Replace all `\` with `\\` in `"E:\PYTHON\0267_Docusign.pdf"`
- Use raw string `r"E:\PYTHON\0267_Docusign.pdf"`

Comment: awesome but now i get an error "RuntimeError: Invalid input format! Got "pdf" but expected one of these: commonmark, creole, docbook, docx,and so on...